# Twitter Unsupported Authentication Problem - Tweetinvi Streams V2 - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: twitter, asp.net-core-mvc, twitter-streaming-api, tweetinvi, twitter-api-v2

When I try to use Tweetinvi Streams V2, it gives an error in the StartAsync section.

```
public async Task streamFonk()
        {
            stream.TweetReceived += (sender, eventReceived) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(eventReceived.Tweet);
            };
            var pars = new StartFilteredStreamV2Parameters();
            pars.ClearCustomQueryParameters();
            pars.ClearAllFields();
            pars.UserFields = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "tolgaylmzyzlm" });
            try
            {
                await stream.StartAsync(pars);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

error: https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream

I get the same error when using Tweetinvi Stream V1.1.